# .Unbind doesnt work with vimeo

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

Im tryin to embed a vimeo-video to my website by using jQyuery. When you click on **Button** the video is displaying. And when you press **close** it haves to close and come back to his original state.
The embedding works great, but the closing of the video doesnt work. I think i do something wrong with unbinding.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".button").bind("click", openVideo);
jQuery(".closeVideo").bind("click", closeVideo);

function openVideo(){
    alert(event.target.id);
    jQuery(this).closest('.post').animate({width: "955px"}, 500);
    jQuery(this).closest('#new-royalslider-1').hide();
    jQuery(this).closest('.post').children('.videoplayer').show();
    jQuery(this).closest('.post').children('.videoplayer').html('<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+ event.target.id +'?autoplay=1" width="100%" height="570" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>');
        }

function closeVideo(){
    alert("close");
    jQuery(".button").unbind("click", openVideo);
}
```

});

What am i doing wrong, close button doesnt bring to the original state

Comment: Did you try `on()` and `off()`? And you realize you're not removing anything but the event handler, the video will still be there ?

Comment: bind, unbind, delegate...they are all just wrappers around on and off

Comment: i am not so familiar with on() off(), i think i am on a the wrong pad with .bind() and unbind(). im a little bit confused. Does someone have an other solution to bring the website to original state. Or am i on the good pad

Comment: @AdemAk [Here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is the `.on()` documentation. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/off/) is the `.off()` documentation.

Comment: What's the intended functionality? Are you trying to remove the video and show the slider again, or just make it so clicking the button no longer works after the first click (which is what you're doing now) ?

Comment: exactly im trying to remove te video and show slider again.